# How to make sure that the element is not visible and proceed with the next conditions in protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am testing an element that when a user selects a radiobutton, a loading image will appear in the middle, and will be invisible after a few seconds. When the loading image disappears, it should show the login screen and do all the other conditions. Below is my protractor code:

```
it('Displays the small login screen', function () {
    var loadpanel = element(by.id("loadingimage"));
    var el = loadpanel;
    browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsNotVisible(el));
    smallLogin = element(by.id('loginScreen'));
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(smallLogin), 30000);
    expect(smallLogin.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    element(by.id('dropdown')).click();
```

This doesn't work, but it passes. I want the loading image to be hidden and until it is visible, the small login condition should not be executed. What happens is that it executes the small login condition and the dropdown click as well, while the image is still visible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Expected Condition you want to use is [`invisibilityOf`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.invisibilityOf):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

// select a radiobutton 

var loadpanel = element(by.id("loadingimage"));
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(loadpanel), 5000);

var smallLogin = element(by.id('loginScreen'));
expect(browser.isElementPresent(smallLogin)).toBe(true);

element(by.id('dropdown')).click();
```

Also, in a similar case and while testing an internal Angular application, I remember also having to set the `ignoreSynchronization` to `true` before the test and set it to `false` after in order to catching a "loading" state of the app.

Comment: I have assigned the ignoreSynchronization = true under beforeEach. I am not sure if this is a good practice? or, that can be acceptable and I will set it to false after I am done with the expected conditions?

Comment: @Marj better set it back to `false` in `afterEach`.

Comment: If I understand the beforeEach - will run before every 'it' and afterEach - will run after every 'it'? please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I had to specify the class/id where the loading image itself is in. I had issues earlier due to not specifying the exact class where the loading image is located.